# Simplicity of result of differentiation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have differentiated the following:

i) $\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)$

ii) $\arctan(x) + \cot^-1(x)$

iii) $\arctan((a+x)/(1-ax))-\arctan(x)$

and all three give a result of zero.

Could anybody explain why these results are so simple?

I am assuming it's something to do with cancelling when the functions are added together however I can't quite get my head around it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a hint, let's do the first one.

Let's consider a right angled triangle with hypotenuse $1$ with angles $\pi/2, A$, and $B$. Let's say the side opposite $A$ is $a$ and the side opposite $B$ is $b$. Then $\arcsin(a) = A = \arccos(b)$ and $\arcsin(b) = \arccos(a) = B$. So you see that $\arcsin(a) + \arccos(a) = A + B = \pi/2$.  Hence the sum of $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ is a constant and when you take the derivative of a constant you get zero.

I am sure that you can figure out the other ones in a similar fashion.

Comment: can I have help with the iii) please? I understand i) and ii) but I am struggling to set up my triangle for iii) so that all relevant information is available. Thank you